# Что значит деградировать. Нужно ли "деградировать" брать в кавычки?

Tags: пунктуация

Название статьи: "Что значит деградировать". Нужно ли "деградировать" брать в кавычки?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что значит "деградировать"

В названии статьи **кавычки нужны**, так как имеется в виду: Что значит (слово) "деградировать"

В Нацкорпусе, к примеру, кавычки пишут, если речь идет о разъяснении смысла слова, например:

*Я смутно понимал, что значит «отыграюсь», и почему-то решил, что бабушка утопит меня в ванне.*

*― А кто их позвал? ― спросила Ирина. ― Что значит "позвал"? Их же не в гости позвали.*

Comment: Во втором примере не смысл слова)

Comment: А где же он, был вроде))

Comment: Хотя в первом вроде бы тоже, не значение слова, а смысл сказанного. Важный момент: часть предложения с вопросительной интонацией должна быть в конце, чтобы поставить знак вопроса (раз есть вопросительная интонация, то должен быть и вопросительный знак). Часто эту ошибку допускаете.

Comment: В названии статьи вопросительный знак не ставят.  Вы же не спрашиваете, а рассказать хотите.

Comment: *А где же он, был вроде* — имею в виду это.

Answer (score 1):

да, надо, если речь о слове, и нет, если речь о смысле, но в данном контексте кавычки сами просятся, так как это вопрос с прямым указанием

"ино"-словечко
де - отделение, отталкивание от чего либо, (часто в европейских фамилиях, как указатель на происхождение)
град - ограждённое, целое (ГРАД - город; виноГРАД; ГРАДус)

деградировать - отталкиваться от целого, покидать целостность